# How can assign a synthesizable string to a byte array in SystemVerilog?

Tags: verilog, hdl, system-verilog

I want to initialize a byte array (or any other possible type) to a long string. For example define: `string str = "abcdefg"`. I read these two links ([1](http://www.alteraforum.com/forum/showthread.php?t=41286) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100692/verilog-multi-dimensional-reg-error)) but I couldn't find a simple way. These are two hard code ways which I found:

1_ `byte str [0:7]; = '{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"};`
This is not an appropriate way, because the string is very long in my real application and I can't write them letter by letter.

2_ Using string type :`string str = "abcdefg"`. But it can only be simulated and isn't synthesizable. Quartus just allows defining string in function or task. So I use the function `getStr()` for initializing string :

```
typedef byte string_t[0:7];

function string_t getStr();
    int i;
    string tmp_str = "abcdefgh";            
    string_t str;

    for(i=0; i<8; i=i+1)
        str[i]=tmp_str[i];

    return str;
endfunction
```

and use it in my code :

```
byte str [0:7];
always @(posedge clk) begin 
     str = getStr(); // str will be "abcdefg" after getStr() return it.
     //The rest of the code...
end
```

I think there must be a better and simpler way for initialize a string in SystemVerilog. If you know it help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this without using string types. Just use a bit-stream cast

```
string_t str = string_t'("abcdefg");
```

This works because a string literal (what is enclosed in "") is interpreted as a 64-bit integral value, and as long as the target variable has the same number of total bits, the bits will be streamed from the 64-bit integral to the fixed array of 8-bits X 8-elements array.